# Newish to Blender and desperatly need help with textures

Tags: texturing

So I've had Blender for about 1.5 months now and have been playing around with it. With a friend we have decided to make a third person tank game so he is doing the coding while I'm doing the art. 
[image]
[image]
This is the first tank I've come up with, rigged and all, and am pretty happy with how it turned out. However, as soon as I try to do any texturing whether it be jpgs or even Poliigons texture files I just struggle so hard with making it look good. As far as I've gotten is give the mud flaps and side panels a weird looking camouflage. Ideally, I am hoping to texture it to a similar standard that the model is rather than a primary schoolers colouring in book. Any tips and tricks or even links to useful videos would be amazing. Thanks to anyone that comments.

Comment: Hello and welcome. This site is more geared towards focused questions about specific problems. Try editing your question to explain exactly what you did and where you are stuck

Answer (score 0):

These tuts might be helpful https://youtu.be/eiDrRa6JvQ0 this next tut is spread across several videos it covers modeling to render just pick the one(s) you want https://youtu.be/XVA8CYC9z2o and if these don't work try googling it. Hope you have success -- triplex

Answer (score 0):

This is a wide topic, but if you want some specific, useful knowledge then I recommend the DOTA 2 art guide. It covers how the principles of art are to be applied: how Silhouette, tone, color, and composition directly affect gameplay readability and appeal, specifically in the area of texturing.

https://support.steampowered.com/kb/9334-YDXV-8590/dota-2-workshop-character-art-guide

While this is a guide for a just one game with one type of stylisation, the concepts all apply universally and are essential to understand for designing your own game's style.

Comment: Looks interesting will have a look!